# DataInput for Vertical UICollectionView in a UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

My problem is the following, how can I implement a `UICollectionView` into a `UITableViewCell` (of my `UITableViewController`), and populate the Data that will load into the `UICollectionView` from my `UITableViewController`.

I'm aware of how to set the different Components up but I don't know how to populate the Data in my `UICollectionView` through the `-cellForRow...` method of my `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you've tried. People will be reluctant to offer help without signs that you've approached the problem yourself already.

Comment: I'm not asking for a fullbaked solution, but just for a method of how to try to solve this Problem. What I've tried isn't really of any useful Information and believe me i've been sitting on this problem for 5 hours.

Comment: I found that most times when I can't figure out how to do something a certain way, its because that is a bad way to do it.  Your tableviewcontroller doesn't really know your collection view, why should it serve up its data?  Perhaps you should pass through information about the data to the cell in a subclassed init call in cellForRow and in that init pass it on to a custom controller that serves up the data to your collectionView.  Make it the data source for your collection view.

Comment: Five hours is not much... I think what you may be looking for is Dependency Injection. Furthermore, what do you mean by a vertical `UICollectionView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go through this-

Create a usual UITableView and in your UITableViewCell create the UICollectionView. Your collectionView delegate and datasource should conform to that UITableViewCell.

In your ViewController

```
// Global Variable
var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)

    tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "NormalCell")
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        var cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()
        return cell

    } else {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NormalCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "cell: \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see I've created two different cells, a custom TableViewCell which is returned only when the row index is 3 and a basic UITableViewCell in other indices.

The custom "TableViewCell" will have our UICollectionView. So Create a UITableViewCell subclass and write down the below code.

```
    import UIKit

    class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        self.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.row%2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }

    return cell
}
}
```

For more you can see this repository - 
https://github.com/DahanHu/DHCollectionTableView

Hope this will will solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I may offer a suggestion to how I would approach this issue, I would create a data source object for the cells that I store a reference to on my table view controller. Consider the following:

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

class TableCellDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cellDataSources: [TableCellDataSource] = []


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = TableCell()
        let dataSource = TableCellDataSource()
        cell.collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
        self.cellDataSources.append(dataSource)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Notice how I now have control over what is displayed by each cell's collection view, from the master table view.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and great answer, will test it right now:)

Comment: Where exactly would I be able to control the data going to the collection view in your method?